# How to use IMPORTXML to extract a list of images with/without ALT and title tags?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have just started using Google sheet's "IMPORTXML" formular to extract webpage meta data for a SEO project.

I am stuck with the following questions:

- How to use this formular and XPATH to extract a list of images (on a
  page), which don't have an alt tag?
- Similar as the question above,   how to extract a list of images (on a page), which have an alt tag?
- How to extract a list of images (on a page), which do or don't have a
  title tag?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Note: 
See an example of my question [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ct6KJEYE9rwWx7Bk5TFB8O50pVG2CFOCjNAZ--NkShw/edit?ts=5d3fdbf1#gid=0):

I also referenced the formular on this post http://slesinsky.org/brian/code/xpath_checker.html, which is very old and seemd no longer working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the images that have an `alt` tag, use

```
=IMPORTXML(A2, "//img/@alt")
```

For those that don't, use

```
=IMPORTXML(A2, "//img[not(./@alt)]")
```

Note that in your example, there is only one `img` with no `alt`, so the cell will appear empty, but the selection is made.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanation, Jack, this works for me!